# Projection operator onto support of distinct observables

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, linear-algebra, observables

Suppose $P_i$ is the projection operator onto the support of the observable $O_i$ defined on some (say, finite dimensional) Hilbert space. I'm curious as to whether we can define the projection operator $P_{1,2}$ onto the *joint* support of, say, both $O_1$ and $O_2$ in terms of $P_1$ and $P_2$, and wonder under what conditions this is possible.

Here, it also seems important to clarify what I mean by 'joint', as this is probably ambiguous. I'm referring to the space that contains both the entire support of $O_1$ and the entire support of $O_2$. Of course, these are vector space notions so speaking of unions and intersections is probably not wise but I'm unsure how else to best describe these notions - I'm referring to something more like the union than the intersection.

Comment: If $H_1$ is the subspace that $P_1$ projects onto, and $H_2$ is the subspace that $P_2$ projects onto, their join is the subspace $H_1 + H_2$, and there is a (self-adjoint) projection onto $H_1 + H_2$.  However, I'm not sure there's a simple formula if $P_1$ and $P_2$ don't commute.  In case $P_1, P_2$ commute the formula is $P_1+P_2-P_1 P_2$.

Comment: @ChadK Thanks, this clarifies a bit. Now I'm curious how one would arrive at that formula when $P_1, P_2$ commute - where might I find this? Or otherwise, how would I derive it? Furthermore, I wonder how the projector onto $P_{1,2}$ would act on the observables $O_1, O_2$ by conjugation? We have that $P_1O_1P_1 = O_1$ and similarly for $P_2, O_2$ given that $P_i$ projects onto the support of $O_i$ , but does $P_{(1,2)}$ generally inherit the property $P_{(1,2)}O_iP_{(1,2)} = O_i$ for $i=1,2$ as well?

Comment: @CosmasZachos I'm afraid that would require me to assume that the two matrices have a common basis in which they are diagonal, which is tantamount to assuming commutation of the projectors - something I wouldn't like to necessarily have. Is there something else I could try to do to clarify my query?

Comment: @Theoreticalhelp:  That's long to answer in a comment.  Do you want me to answer the questions in your comment as an answer to the original post?

Comment: @ChadK, Please do!

Comment: What do you mean by "support" of an observable?

Comment: @ValterMoretti The notion I have in mind is that the support of $O$ is the subspace of the Hilbert space that is the orthogonal complement of the kernel of the bounded linear operator $O$.

Comment: So it is the range of $O$ in finite dimension.

Comment: @ValterMoretti I do suppose so, yes. Although, slightly rusty on the exact definition but I vaguely recall that this is true because O is self adjoint.

Comment: Yes, just because it is selfadjoint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an answer to the comment.  Let $H_1$ and $H_2$ be two closed subspaces of a Hilbert space.  Let $H_{1,2} = H_1 + H_2$ be the closure of the algebraic sum of the subspaces.  (Note: In finite dimension all subspaces are closed, so the mention of closure is redundant.)  $H_{1,2}$ is the join of the two subspaces in the lattice of closed subspaces of the given Hilbert space.

Let $P_1$ and $P_2$ be the orthogonal projections on $H_1$ and $H_2$.  There is also an orthogonal projection $P_{1,2}$ on $H_{1,2}$.

Now, assuming $P_1, P_2$ commute, there is an expression for $P_{1,2}$ which is $P_1 + P_2 - P_1 P_2$.  First, note that $P_1, P_2$ commute if and only if the subspaces $H_1\cap (H_1 \cap H_2)^\perp, H_2\cap (H_1\cap H_2)^\perp$ are orthogonal to each other.  Next, notice that $P_1 P_2 = P_2 P_1$ is the orthogonal projection on $H_1 \cap H_2$.

Now, if $v\perp H_{1,2}$, then $v\perp H_1$ and $v\perp H_2$ so $(P_1+P_2-P_1 P_2)v = 0$.  Furthermore, any $u\in P_{1,2}$ can be (uniquely) decomposed as an orthogonal sum of three vectors $u = x + y + z$ where $x\in H_1\cap (H_1 \cap H_2)^\perp$, $y\in H_1\cap H_2$ and $z\in H_2\cap (H_1 \cap H_2)^\perp$.  Moreover, $y = P_1 P_2 u$, $x = (P_1 - P_1 P_2)u$ and $z=(P_2 - P_1 P_2)u$ so
$$u = (P_1 - P_1 P_2)u + P_1 P_2 u +(P_2 - P_1 P_2)u = (P_1 + P_2 - P_1 P_2)u$$
So putting the results together, $P_1 + P_2 - P_1 P_2$ is the orthogonal projection on $H_{1,2}$.

Now let's go back to the general case ($P_1, P_2$ don't necessarily commute).  If $v\perp H_{1,2}$ then $v\perp H_1$ and $v\perp H_2$, and since $O_1, O_2$ are supported on $H_1, H_2$ respectively, we have $O_1 v = O_2 v = 0$.  Furthermore, since $O_1, O_2$ are self-adjoint, we have $O_1^\dagger v = O_1 v = 0$ and $O_2^\dagger v = O_2 v = 0$.  From this it follows that both $O_1$ and
$O_2$ map $H_{1,2}$ into itself.  For example, if $u\in H_{1,2}$ and $v$ as before then
$$\langle O_i u, v\rangle = \langle u, O_i^\dagger v\rangle = \langle u, 0 \rangle = 0$$
and this holds for all $v\perp H_{1,2}$ which proves that $O_i u\in H_{1,2}$.
So putting the above together, $H_{1,2}$ and its orthogonal complement are stable under $O_i$ which implies that $O_i$ both commute with $P_{1,2}$, i.e. $P_{1,2} O_i P_{1,2} = O_i$.  This part holds even in the case $P_1, P_2$ don't commute.

Answer (score 2):

The space you are looking for is the sum of the two spaces.
The orthogonal projector is denoted by $$P_1\vee P_2$$
where $P_i$ are the projectors on the subspaces.
Actually the wanted space is the closure of the sum, but in finite dimension, all subspaces are closed.

It holds, in view of De Morgan law
$$P_1 \vee P_2 = I -((I- P_1)\wedge(I- P_2)).$$
Here
$$Q_i= I-P_i$$ is the orthogonal projector onto the orthogonal to the projection space of $P_i$. In your case, it is just the projector onto the kernel of the considered observable.
$$Q_1 \wedge Q_2$$
is the projector onto the intersection of the projection subspaces of $Q_1$ and $Q_2$.

There is a nice result due to von Neumann, valid also in the infinite dimensional case:
$$Q_1\wedge Q_2\psi = \lim_{n\to +\infty} (Q_1Q_2)^n\psi$$
for all vectors $\psi$ of the space.

Notice that, in case the projectors commute, in particular when the observables are compatible, the formula boils down to
$$Q_1\wedge Q_2=Q_1Q_2$$
In this case, with a little algebra from the formulas above,
$$P_1\vee P_2 = P_1+P_2 -P_1P_2.$$
In the general case
$$P_1 \vee P_2 \psi  = \psi -\lim_{n\to +\infty}((I- P_1)(I- P_2))^n\psi.$$
In other words, the general formula is
$$P_{joint \: supp\: O_1, O_2}\psi = \psi - \lim_{n\to +\infty} (P_{Ker(O_1)}P_{Ker(O_2)})^n\psi$$

Comment: Excellent, thanks. I'm not too familiar with the exact definitions of these wedge products (I assume that is what they are), certainly not when placed between the projectors. Please could you direct me to where I might find literature on this, or, if I may dare hassle you further, define them instead?

Comment: The wedge is jus a symbol: $P\wedge Q$ is by definition the  orthogonal projector onto  the intersection subspace $P(H)\cap Q(H)$.  Similarly $P\vee Q$ is the orthogonal projector  onto the closure of the sum of subspaces $P(H)+Q(H)$. The set of orthogonal projectros equipped with those two symbols and the orthocomplement operation $P^\perp = I-P$ is a lattice which satisfies the De Morgan law.